# What values of 'a' and 'b' would create a unique, no, and infinite solution(s)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

The following problem has really troubled me: 
[image]

I have row reduced it, so now it looks more like this: 
[image]

How do I really figure out what values of a and b would create infinitely many solutions, no solutions, or a unique solutions?

Comment: Think about solving. You would now put $x_3=\frac{2b-1}{b+1}$. How could that fail? Well suppose $b=-1$, Then the last equation would simply read $0=-4$, which is false, so there are no solutions. So suppose $b\ne-1$. Now you can solve for $x_2$. But how might that go wrong? etc

Answer (score 1):

Based on your calculations, the determinant of the coefficient matrix is $a(b-1)(b+1)$. So if $a\neq0$ and $b\neq\pm1$, there is certainly a unique solution.

If $b=-1$, the last row of your reduced matrix says $0=-4$, so there is no solution.

If $b=1$, then the second (and third) row of your reduced matrix says that $x_3=0$. The first row says $ax_1+x_2=1$, so $x_2=1-ax_1$. You can let $x_2$ be any real number, so there are infinitely many solutions.

If $a=0$, and $b\neq\pm1$, then you can reduce the third column to get:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&-\frac12(b+1)b&0&-\frac12(b+1)+(2b-2)\\
0&-(b+1)(b-1)&0&2b-2\\
0&0&b+1&2b-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&-\frac12b^2-\frac12b&0&\frac32b-\frac52\\
0&-(b+1)(b-1)&0&2b-2\\
0&0&b+1&2b-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

The top two equations only admit a solution if 
$$\begin{align}
\left(-\frac12b^2-\frac12b\right)(2b-2)
&=-(b+1)(b-1)\left(\frac32b-\frac52\right)
\\
\left(-b^2-b\right)(b-1)
&=-(b+1)(b-1)\left(\frac32b-\frac52\right)
\\
-b(b+1)
&=-(b+1)\left(\frac32b-\frac52\right)\\
-b
&=\frac32b-\frac52\\
-\frac52b
&=-\frac52\\
b
&=5
\end{align}
$$

So when $a=0$, there is no solution unless $b=5$, in which case $x_3$ and $x_2$ are uniquely determined, but $x_1$ can take any value.